# Batch file get start and end char inside for loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Hello i am struggling to figure out how i can get the end char of a string variable in a Batch file.
I can easily get the first char using **SET subStr=!sub:~1,1!** but all i really want to do is find if a string contains **~** so i tried a few examples but because i am doing this inside a for loop its more of a challenge.I have a function to get the string length which works fine but i just can not figure out how to use the variables with the sub command I.E.

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /b "%protoDir%" *.proto 2^>NUL') DO (
  :: Check and ignore tilde temp files which start or ends with ~
  SET sub=%%i 

  call :strLen sub str
  ECHO strLength=!str! 
  SET /A len=!str!-1
  ECHO length - 1 = !len!
  SET subStr2="!sub:~!len!,!len!!"  <-- ERROR IS HERE
  ECHO !subStr2!

  SET subStr=!sub:~1,1!   
  IF NOT !subStr! == ~ (
    IF NOT !subStr2! == ~ ( SOME CODE HERE... )
  )
)

:: Function to get a strings length 
:strLen
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:strLen_Loop
if not "!%1:~%len%!"=="" set /A len+=1 & goto :strLen_Loop
(endlocal & set %2=%len%)
goto :eof
```

Output is:

strLength=26

length - 1 = 25

"ReceiverDiagnostics.proto lenlen"  *which instead should be **~***

I would prefer to use the code below which is far more simple but i can not get to to work inside the for loop even with !.

```
IF NOT "%foobar%"=="%foobar:~=%" ( ECHO string contains ~ )
```

Comment: The expression `!sub:~1,1!` actually returns the *second* character. Anyway, to check if a strin contains `~` you could do `if not "!sub!"=="!sub:*~=!" echo String contains '~'.` (note the `*`)...

Comment: Surely it makes more sense to pass the result of your `Dir` command line through [tag:find] or better [tag:findstr], to filter out filenames starting and/or ending with a tilde, instead of passing them to `Do` and then filtering with `If`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true that you cannot use the expression `!sub:~=!`, because this conflicts with the [sub-string *expansion* syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) (e. g., `!sub:~1,1!`) and the [sub-string *substitution* syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) (e. g., `!sub:search=replace!`).

However, you can use the following special case of the sub-string replacement feature `!sub:*search=replace!`, which replaces everything up to and including the first occurrence of `search` by `replace`, because the search string is then allowed to begin with a `~`:

```cmd
if not "!sub!"=="!sub:*~=!" echo String contains '~'.
```